# Monotouch JIT error on device with LINQ

Tags: iphone, linq, xamarin.ios, jit, aot

I am trying to run our application on an iOS device through the Debug|iPhone option in MonoTouch. We run into a problem quite fast however. The application crashes with the following exception

```
Attempting to JIT compile method "System.Linq.Enumerable:<FirstOfDefault`1>m_13<int> (int)" while running with aot-only.
```

Now I understand this problem comes from the generic part being JIT, which is not allowed on the actual iOS device. What I can't find out though is how to fix it.

Below is the code where it crashes:

```
int nextTag = (from tag in _cellControllers.Keys
    where tag > currentTag
    select tag).FirstOrDefault();
```

_cellControllers is a

```
Dictionary <int, UITableViewSource>
```

How can I prevent this error from happening?

Comment: Exactly which kind of generic Dictionary?

Comment: See my initial post. Had to edit it, so it would show the type because of formating here on stackoverflow. heh :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is having value types as keys in the dictionary, as documented [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations#Value_types_as_Dictionary_Keys). Changing the dictionary to not have a value type as key will possibly make this case work (unfortunately in some cases LINQ will use dictionaries by itself, in which case it would be required to rewrite the query).

We're working on fixing these issues while using LINQ, so I'd also suggest [filing a bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a compilable test case so we can ensure your case works in the future.

Comment: Hello. I rewrote the code to use a List instead of a Dictionary, since I could retrieve the tag through other means. This fixed my problem and the LINQ-code works now fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You are likely hitting a [AOT](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT#Full_AOT) [limitation](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations) (like this [one](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations#Value_types_as_Dictionary_Keys)) where the AOT compiler was not able to determine correctly the types to compile, ahead of time, to ensure the code could work at runtime.

> How can I prevent this error from happening?

Solution depends on what exact limitation is being hit. LINQ queries generates a lot of IL code so it's not always apparent to developers (or the apt compiler) what's being generated. That makes working around the issue a bit harder.

To get to the bottom of such issues we'll need quite  but of information so filling a bug report, on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com , is a lot better. E.g.

The most important part is the device logs which you can get by running the following in a terminal window:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --logdev
```

Then execute/crash your application and copy-paste the output, on the terminal, into the bug report (or add it as an attachment).